# Database Structure txt file comparison using python

Tags: python

I have 2 unloaded DB structure text files (one before upgrade and one after the upgrade). This is just the DB/Table structure - like `TableName, ColumnName, DataTpe, DataLength, ColumnOrder`.
During the DB Upgrade, some new tables and columns (to existing tables) are added, some columns are dropped. Also, the DataType/DataLength of the TableName.Column can change (Ex: int can change to bigint, varchar(100) can change to varchar(500) ).

A part of Unloaded DB Structure before upgrade:

```
employee,Emp_id,int,,1
employee,Emp_L_Name,varchar,10,2
employee,Emp_F_Name,varchar,20,3
employee,Emp_Gender,varchar,6,4
employee,Emp_dept,int,,5
TableA,ColumnA1,int,,1
TableA,ColumnA2,varchar,100,2
TableB,ColumnB1,bigint,,1
TableB,ColumnB2,varchar,10,2
```

A part of Unloaded DB Structure After upgrade:

```
employee,Emp_id,bigint,,1
employee,Emp_L_Name,varchar,20,2
employee,Emp_F_Name,varchar,30,3
employee,Emp_Gender,varchar,6,4
employee,Emp_Sal,int,,5
TableB,ColumnB1,bigint,,1
TableB,ColumnB2,varchar,10,2
TableB,ColumnB3,smallint,,3
TableC,ColumnC1,int,,1
TableC,ColumnC2,varchar,100,2
```

The EMPLOYEE table structure is just a part of the unloaded DB structure file. There are more than 200 tables in the same DB structure text file.

Can someone suggest an efficient way in python to compare the txt files (before and after upgrade) and find the difference in the DB-- basically by comparing text of the DB structure file (say DB_before.txt and DB_After.txt)? I need the following output:

1. New Tables added.
2. Tables Dropped
3. New Columns added
4. Columns dropped
5. DataType change (like **emp_id from int to bigint**), DataLength changes (Like **emp_L_Name from varchar(10) to varchar(20)**), ColumnOrder change etc.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that gets you these answers specifically for the structure provided in the presented format, or for comparing any two PostgreSQL schemas? What have you tried or considered so far yourself?

Comment: @Grismar -- Looking for a solution (written in python) for structure provided in the presented format in the above example.

Comment: Use [`diff`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm) then parse its output.

Comment: It would appear that parsing the presented text format is very straightforward and the data could be kept in a nested dictionary of table >> field >> type. Obtaining the results you listed would be relatively expressions operating on those two dictionaries. What have you tried yourself? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: So far, I have been reading the before and after text files using readlines() and getting a list of the text. Then comparing the Lists (before and after) which is not a good solution and taking to much time since I have to iterate thru the list every now and then.

Comment: @Grismar -- So what you are saying is that I have two nested dicts (before and after) like `{1: {table: 'value', column:'value', datatype:'value', datalength:'value...}, 2: {table: 'value', column:'value', datatype:'value', datalength:'value...} .....}` and then compare the two dictionaries?

Comment: @P_Ar, not exactly, more like `{'table_name': {'field_name': 'type', ..}, ..}` and compare those. But my suggestion isn't intended as a solution, but as a prompt to suggest you come up with a solution and if you have trouble getting it to work (or to get some of the values you need) ask about that specifically, instead of presenting the problem and asking for a brand new solution without offering your own. No offense intended, just trying to be clear about how SO typically works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you should really provide an example of what you tried - both to get a better answer and to learn something in the process - I thought the problem was interesting enough to solve over coffee.

Here's my attempt:

```
from io import StringIO
from collections import defaultdict

# instead of files, these are memory objects, but they behave just like open files would
text1 = StringIO("""employee,Emp_id,int,,1
employee,Emp_L_Name,varchar,10,2
employee,Emp_F_Name,varchar,20,3
employee,Emp_Gender,varchar,6,4
employee,Emp_dept,int,,5
TableA,ColumnA1,int,,1
TableA,ColumnA2,varchar,100,2
TableB,ColumnB1,bigint,,1
TableB,ColumnB2,varchar,10,2""")

text2 = StringIO("""employee,Emp_id,bigint,,1
employee,Emp_L_Name,varchar,20,2
employee,Emp_F_Name,varchar,30,3
employee,Emp_Gender,varchar,6,4
employee,Emp_Sal,int,,5
TableB,ColumnB1,bigint,,1
TableB,ColumnB2,varchar,10,2
TableB,ColumnB3,smallint,,3
TableC,ColumnC1,int,,1
TableC,ColumnC2,varchar,100,2""")


def dict_from_text(f):
    structure = defaultdict(dict)
    for line in f:
        # split, ignoring the line ending
        parts = line.strip().split(',')
        # this next line is for clarity, I would suggest merging it with the next
        table, field, field_type = parts[0], parts[1], parts[2] if not parts[3] else f'{parts[2]}({parts[3]})'
        structure[table][field] = field_type
    return structure


structure1 = dict_from_text(text1)
structure2 = dict_from_text(text2)

# with the dicts, answering the questions is easy
new_tables_added = structure2.keys() - structure1.keys()
print(f'tables added: {new_tables_added}')

tables_dropped = structure1.keys() - structure2.keys()
print(f'tables dropped: {tables_dropped}')

columns_added = {t: structure2[t].keys() - structure1[t].keys() for t in structure2 if t in structure1}
print(f'columns added: {columns_added}')

columns_dropped = {t: structure1[t].keys() - structure2[t].keys() for t in structure1 if t in structure2}
print(f'columns dropped: {columns_dropped}')

# the last one is a bit more challenging in one comprehension, but still readable if you spread it a bit
field_type_changes = {
    t: {
        v: (structure1[t][v], structure2[t][v]) 
        for v in structure1[t].keys() 
        if v in structure2[t] and structure1[t][v] != structure2[t][v]
    } for t in structure1 if t in structure2
}
print(f'field types changed: {field_type_changes}')
```

Result:

```
tables added: {'TableC'}
tables dropped: {'TableA'}
columns added: {'employee': {'Emp_Sal'}, 'TableB': {'ColumnB3'}}
columns dropped: {'employee': {'Emp_dept'}, 'TableB': set()}
datatypes changed: {'employee': {'Emp_id': ('int', 'bigint'), 'Emp_L_Name': ('varchar(10)', 'varchar(20)'), 'Emp_F_Name': ('varchar(20)', 'varchar(30)')}, 'TableB': {}}
```

If you prefer the elements that have an empty set or empty dictionary to indicate no change not to be in the result, that's left as an exercise, I guess. There's plenty of other answers on SO explaining how to do that and putting it in now would have taken away from the clean solution I had.

Comment: Thank you very much.